# Two tables in one ( java )

Tags: java

I want to create a table T containing two tables T1 and T2.

T1[]={column1_name = value1 , column2_name = value2 ...}.
The same structure for T2

```
T[] = {T1[],T2[]}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a multi dimensional array, something like `T[][]`

Comment: Zied, how did you declare T1?

Comment: what you tried so far can you show us your effort?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the follow method:
Declare class T:

```
class T {
    String column;
    String value;
}
```

And then declare the array of type T:

```
T[][] array = {
                 {new T(), new T()}, 
                 {new T(), new T()}
               }
```

To recap, you have the same structure that you want.